# Get server date to compute days until Friday

Tags: linux, shell-script, date

I'm trying to get the current date of my school server (I don't have root access) to complete this task:

> Write a script that will countdown to Friday(example: output would be "Today is Sunday, you have 5 days until Friday"). You should use the time and day from the server, not the user.

Comment: Have you encountered the `date` command?

Comment: What have you tried? What is not working? https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: date command shows the computer date and time, is that correct? I've tried ntpdate, rsh <host name> date, uptime

Comment: Type `man date`. Read the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged Linux, you have a powerful `date` utility at your disposal. Here's how I might approach such a task (depending on what you want to have happen if today *is* Friday -- this will take you into the *next* week):

```
now=$(date +%s)
fri=$(date +%s -d "next Friday")
days=$(( (fri - now) / 86400))
echo Today is $(date +%A), you have $days until Friday
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start:

```
date "+Today is %A"

date "+The current day of the week as an integer is %u"
```

Have a look at the manual for the `date` command.

Answer (score -1):

Using `dateutils` to print today's date:

```
$ dateconv -f "Anno Domini %OY %Om %Od" now
Anno Domini MMXVII IV XXX
```